# Escaping out of (or exiting) a Compiled Function

Tags: compile, message-coding

How do I manually escape out of a compiled function without forcing an error and compromising its speed?

Here is an example:

```
f::zero = "x is zero.";

f = Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, If[x == 0, Return[1/x], x^2], 
"RuntimeOptions" -> {"RuntimeErrorHandler" -> 
  Function[Message[f::zero]; Throw[$Failed]]}];
```

As you can see, I want `f` to throw an error when `x=0`, but in order to do that, I needed to artificially think there *actually was an error* by returning `1/x`.  Here is the usage:

```
Catch[f[0]]
```

> CompiledFunction::cfne : Numeriacal Error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >> 
>   
>  f::zero : x is zero

1. How do I prevent the kernel from *proceeding with uncompiled evaluation of the artificial 1/0* like it says (which I believe compromises speed).
2. How do I escape out of a CompiledFunction without mimicking an error?

Comment: You could use a wrapper function that calls the compiled function and that catches numeric error codes, for instance in this case negative numbers and acts on them.

Comment: The uncompiled evaluation on returning an infinite or not-a-number value seems to be hard-wired in the VM. I don't think it's possible to avoid that except as described by Sjoerd.

Comment: Ok, it looks like @SjoerdC.deVries 's method works and doesn't compromise the speed too much (at least in the cases I'm working on)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries would you kindly turn your comment into an answer.  I'll accept and this question will go off the unanswered list.

Comment: @QuantumDot OK, done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f::zero = "x is zero.";

f = Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, 
   If[x == 0, Throw[Message[f::zero]; $Failed]; Return[1/x], x^2]];

Catch[f[0]]
```

[image: Out]

Or

```
f = With[{cf = Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, If[x == 0, Throw[Message[f::zero]; $Failed], x^2]]}, 
     Catch[cf[#]] &];

f[0]
```

[image: Out]

In the case of `x == 0` there will be one (thanks to [the comment by Oleksandr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66878/escaping-out-of-or-exiting-a-compiled-function/99935#comment271302_99935)) `MainEvaluate` call, but it shouldn't have a more significant impact on the speed than [using a wrapper function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99926/18476).

Comment: Why not return `$Failed`, rather than throwing it, so the calling function doesn't have to be wrapped in `Catch` to have good behavior?

Comment: @m_goldberg Because of type inconsistency.

Comment: This is an excellent solution, especially if you're going to have to postprocess the return value anyway. Incidentally, the two calls out to the top level can be made into one by moving `Message` inside `Throw`, although I'm not sure that this really matters in practice.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Although I couldn't find a measurable speed difference, I do prefer having only one `MainEvaluate`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[f, fc]
f::zero = "x is zero.";

(* compiled part *)
fc =
  Compile[{{x, _Complex}},
   (* First part of the code; can be anything 
      .
      .
   *)
   If[x == 0, (* Error test*)
    {0, 0}, (* Error response, first part is status, second part is dummy *)
    {1, x^2} (* Normal response, first part is status, second part actual result *)
   ]
];

(* wrapper part *)
f[x_] := With[{res = fc[x]}, 
  If[Chop[res[[1]]] == 0, (* check status *)
    Message[f::zero]; $Failed, (* error *)
    res[[2]] (* normal result *)
  ]]

f[0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[1]
(* 1. + 0. I *)
```

or with MichaelE2's suggestion:

```
ClearAll[f, fc]
f::zero = "x is zero.";

fc =
  Compile[{{x, _Complex}},
   (* First part of the code *)
   If[x == 0, (* Error test*)
    {},(* Error response, empty list *)
    {x^2} (* Normal response, list with result *)
    ]
   ];
f[x_] := With[{res = fc[x]}, If[res == {}, Message[f::zero]; $Failed, First@res]]
```

Comment: I might consider indicating the error by returning an empty array and a normal result in extra set of braces: E.g.,  `If[x == 0, {}, {x^2}]`.  The empty array needs to be of the same rank as the other result.  (Just an alternative for folks to choose from.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good idea. Updated the answer.

Comment: `Catch` and `Throw` are compilable. Therefore this answer could easily be modified to have an early escape.

Comment: @MichaelE2 There will be an extra `ArrayReshape` when using an empty array. Shouldn't be significant for the speed, though.

Comment: @Karsten7. Yes, I knew that and also thought it was unimportant. Note that `Return` is compilable, too.  I find Sjoerd's method consistently faster than yours, though again only by an unimportant amount.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Strange, on my PC [my version is faster](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G9CqU.png) (Also after changing the [execution order](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8UnSD.png)).

Comment: @Karsten7. As I said, it's not important. http://i.stack.imgur.com/xg1xD.png (Sjoerd's is 2nd; I had already put `Message` inside `Throw`, but it didn't seem to matter).

Comment: @MichaelE2 BTW, are you aware of the existence of `RepeatedTiming`?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yep. The timing is, I think, proportional to a linear combination of #messages and #iterations. `RepeatedTiming` won't tease out those coefficients. Printing the message takes something like 10000 times as long as running the program, so speed is really unimportant. I was just responding to Karsten's remark about speed. What's more important is whether to signal an error with one's own internal code, e.g. `{}`, or the built-in function `Throw`. (I tend to agree with Oleksandr.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 the other great advantage of using `Throw`, and which I think would outweigh any performance differences, is that you can put in it whatever you want--any values generated inside the compiled code; arbitrary top-level code; diagnostic messages... it is a lot more useful than just a numeric flag.